# Apache LogFormat: what does %f mean?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, logging, apache2, apache-1.3

I have checked the apache logformat from - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html

I am not able to understand what does "%f" parameter mean in apache log format. The description given for this parameter is "Filename". But it does not elaborate which filename. In my case it shows referer url of the http request made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first test system I tried, with  Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS):

As expected  `%f` logs a filename.

To be exact the absolute filename (including path) of the file system location that the web server used to complete the request (or attempted to use in case of a non-existent file).

As far as I could see, that filename `%f` is the end result after expanding aliases and rewrite rules.

I haven't tested what it shows with for example (reverse) proxy requests where Apache httpd doesn't serve a local filesystem resource.

---

```
CustomLog   "|/usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/httpd/example.com_access_log.%Y.%m 86400" "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b - \"%f\""
```

Resulted in entries such as

```
10.10.160.119 - - [05/Jan/2024:12:26:07 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 463 - "/var/www/html/www.example.com/index.html"
10.10.160.119 - - [05/Jan/2024:12:27:12 +0100] "GET /test3 HTTP/1.1" 404 203 - "/var/www/html/www.example.com/test3"
```

Comment: Do you think %f paramater is realted to request_rec::filename parameter or any other parameter from request_rec ? From where does %f picks up the value for filename ?